# Visual Studio f2 refactor.rename, file.rename

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to get Visual Studio to Rename a file when I'm in the solution explorer with a file or directory selected and I hit the F2 key.  However, I also want Visual Studio to do Refactoring Renaming when I hit F2 and I am in the editor window with my cursor on a variable.  I know it is something to do with setting the context of each (Global, TextEditor, etc).  However, I can't seem to find the right combination.  There is no "Solution Explorer" Context

Answer (score 27):

Here's what I did in Visual Studio (2013) to get F2 working in the editor and the solution explorer:

- Go to the **Tools/Options** menu, and select **Environment/Keyboard**
- In "Show commands containing" put **File.Rename**
- In "Use new shortcut in" select **Solution Explorer**
- In "Press shortcut keys" press F2, and click "Assign"
- In "Show commands containing" put **Refactor.Rename**
- In "Use new shortcut in" select **Text Editor**
- In "Press shortcut keys" press F2 and click "Assign"

I couldn't get it to work with "Global". It seems odd to me that this isn't default behaviour, given the ubiquity of using F2 for renaming across Microsoft products, but at least its flexible enough to allow you to set it up.

Comment: It worked this way by default for me, but after installing ReSharper (or perhaps some other change) it stopped working and required the changes in your answer.

Comment: @Sam - when I was trying to figure it out, it seemed people were getting different experiences. I don't have ReSharper though - I think my only plugin is Visual SVN. I first noticed it when I upgraded to 2013, but that may have been coincidence.

Comment: I had F2 assigned by default and use it all the time. I installed Resharper, and now even the above steps won't fix it. I eventually uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio. Resharper will never touch my computer again.

Comment: This is ridiculous. Thank you for this tip, I assign shortcuts all the time, but never used that combo box!

Answer (score 1):

I used Global for the solution explorer and text editor for the text editor...
so far so good